# CSS button with bottom right corner cut

Tags: html, css, sass

I am trying to create a material button component which should look like below.

[image]

Below is the CSS that I tried,

```
div {
  height: 24px;
  background: green;
  position: relative;
  padding-left:8px;
  padding-right:8px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  line-height: 24px;
  display:inline-block;

}

 div:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-bottom: 8px solid white;  //applied white to test, transparent not working
  border-left: 8px solid transparent;
  width: 0;
}
```

HTML Usage

```
<div>
  <span>Complete</span>
</div>
```

The problem is if this button is used with different background color then I am able to see a small triangle at the bottom right, for example like below

[image]

I do want to design with the help of triangle but how could I design this ?

Is my approach or implementation wrong ?

I am using SCSS.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Lev413j6/ --> take a look. I was just about to post this as answer, but just fell short of the question closure. Oh well :/